# ajax call to asp mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to have my ajax make a call to my controller when the "remove' button is clicked. The image preview is being removed, but the breakpoints on my controller never hit. Can someome take a look at my code and shed a little light. Thanks!

```
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    init: function () {
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button id='btnDel' class='btnRemove'>Remove file</button>");
            var _this = this;

            // Listen to the click event
            removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

                _this.removeFile(file);
                var delURL = "~/Home/DeleteFiles";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: delURL,
                    data: param = "",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: alert("worked"),
                    error: errorFunc
                });
            });
            file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
            $(".dz-error-message").remove();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post the Controller code here aswell. You are using POST request. Make sure you have [HttpPost] attribute on that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This URL means nothing to your browser:

```
~/Home/DeleteFiles
```

That `~` character represents a reference to the server-side "home" or "root" path for the application.  But client-side code has no notion of that.  It needs an actual URL.

If the action being invoked is called `DeleteFiles` on the `Home` controller then you can use the URL helper to generate the URL when rendering the client-side code:

```
var delURL = '@Url.Action("DeleteFiles", "Home")';
```

This will use server-side code in the view to generate the actual URL to be used client-side, relative to anything else known server-side about the application.  It would render as something like:

```
var delURL = 'http://yourserver/Home/DeleteFiles';
```